# Failure of Calderón–Zygmund inequality at the endpoints

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, harmonic-analysis

$\newcommand\norm[1]{\lVert#1\rVert}\newcommand\abs[1]{\lvert#1\rvert}$I'd like to prove that the famous Calderón–Zygmund elliptic estimate $$ \norm{ \partial_{ij}u }_{L^p} \leq C \norm{\Delta u }_{L^p} ,$$ valid for $ 1< p  < \infty$ and $u \in C_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ fails at the endpoints $p = 1$ and $p = \infty$. For the $ p = 1$ case, I believe I have a proof, for which I'd be grateful if someone could verify the validity of and/or could find a simpler argument for. Namely, we have the following:

Let $\phi \in C_{c}^{\infty}(B_{1}(0)) $ and $ \phi_{\epsilon}(x) = \epsilon ^{-n}\phi(\frac{x}{\epsilon})  $  and suppose further $ \phi  \geq 0 $ and $\int \phi = 1$. Let $\chi $ be a smooth and non-negative cut-off supported in $ B_{1} $ with $ \chi  = 1 $ in $B_{\frac{1}{2}} $. Set $ \Gamma(x) = \abs x^{2-n} $ (up to a dimensional constant which we neglect for simplicity of exposition). Set $$ u_{\epsilon}(x) =  \chi(x) (\Gamma \ast \phi_{\epsilon}) (x).$$ We first claim that $$\tag{1}\label{1}  \sup_{0 < \epsilon < 1}\norm{\Delta u_{\epsilon} } < +\infty .$$ We have $$  \norm{\Delta u_{\epsilon} } \leq \norm\chi_{L^{\infty}}\norm{\phi_{\epsilon}}_{L^1} + \norm{(\Delta \chi )(\phi_{\epsilon} \ast \Gamma)}_{L^1} + 2 \norm{\nabla \chi \cdot \nabla(\phi_{\epsilon} \ast \Gamma) }_{L^1}.$$ The first term is obviously bounded in $\epsilon$. To estimate the second term we change variables,

\begin{align*}
&\norm{(\Delta \chi)(\phi_{\epsilon} \ast \Gamma) }_{L^1} \\ 
&\leq \int_{ B_{1}(0) }  \left|\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \abs{x-y}^{2-n} \phi_{\epsilon}(y)dy \right|dx \\
&\leq\epsilon^2 \int_{B_{\frac{1}{\epsilon}}(0)} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \abs{x-y}^{2-n}\phi(y)dy\,dx 
\\
&\leq \epsilon^2\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \phi(y)\int_{B_{ \frac{1}{\epsilon}}(0)}\abs{x-y}^{2-n}dx\,dy\\
&\leq \epsilon^2 \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \phi(y)dy \int_{B_{ \frac{1}{ \epsilon }}(0)}\abs x^{2-n}\leq 1 .
\end{align*}
The third term is estimated very similarly to the second term, by changing variables. Thus we have the desired claim $$ \norm{ \Delta u_{\epsilon}}_{L^1} \leq C  , $$ as $ \epsilon \to 0$. Now let $ i$, $j$ be indices between $1 $ and $n$, with $ i \neq j$. We claim $$\tag{2}\label{2} \lim_{\epsilon \to 0}  \norm{\partial_{ij}u_{\epsilon}}_{L^1} = +\infty. $$ To prove this we just need to prove $$ \tag{3}\label{3}  \norm{\partial_{ij} (\phi_{\epsilon} \ast \Gamma )}_{L^1(B_{1})} $$ is unbounded as $\epsilon \to 0 $,  since the other terms are bounded in $\epsilon$. Again by changing variables, we have $$  \norm{\partial_{ij} (\phi_{\epsilon} \ast \Gamma )}_{L^1(B_{1})} = \int_{B_{1}(0)}\left|\partial_{x_{i}x_{j}} \int_{B_{1}(0)} \phi(z)\epsilon^{2-n}\left|\frac{x}{\epsilon}-z\right|^{2-n} dz\right|dx .$$ Now we choose $ \epsilon > 0 $ so small that  that for $z \in B_{1} $ and $ x \in B_{1}\setminus B_{2\epsilon}$, we have the inequality $$ \tag{4}\label{4} \frac{1}{2}\left|\frac{x}{\epsilon}\right| \leq \left|\frac{x}{\epsilon}-z \right| \leq 2\left|\frac{x}{\epsilon}\right|.$$ Additionally, having chosen some $\epsilon_{0}$ as above, we pick a sector $S_{i,j}$ contained in the unit ball, with the properties that for $ x \in S_{i,j}$ , $$ \tag{5}\label{5} \frac{x_{i}}{\epsilon}-1 > \frac{1}{10} \left| \frac{x}{\epsilon}\right|, \hspace{0.5 cm} \frac{x_{j}}{\epsilon}-1 > \frac{1}{10} \left| \frac{x}{\epsilon}\right| , $$ for all $ \epsilon \leq \epsilon_{0} ,$ and such that $$ \tag{6}\label{6} m(S_{i,j} \cap \partial B_{r}(0)) \geq C m(\partial B_{r}(0)) ,$$ for all $ r \leq \epsilon_{0} $, where the constant $C$ above depends only on $\epsilon_{0} $, and $m$ denotes the Hausdorff $n-1$ dimensional surface measure. Suppose from now on $2\epsilon < \epsilon_{0} $. Then we may lower bound \eqref{3} using \eqref{4}, \eqref{5} and \eqref{6} as follows,
\begin{align*}
&\norm{\partial_{ij} (\phi_{\epsilon} \ast \Gamma )}_{L^1(B_{1})} \\ 
& \geq \int_{B_{1}\setminus B_{2\epsilon} \cap S_{i,j} } \left| \partial_{x_{i}x_{j}} \int_{B_{1}(0)} \phi(z)\epsilon^{2-n}\left|\frac{x}{\epsilon}-z\right|^{2-n} dz   \right|dx \\ 
& \geq  \int_{B_{1}\setminus B_{2\epsilon} \cap S_{i,j} } \biggl( \int_{B_{1}(0)}\phi(z)\epsilon^{-n}\frac{(\frac{x_{i}}{\epsilon}-z_{i})(\frac{x_{j}}{\epsilon}-z_{j})}{\left| \frac{x}{\epsilon}-z \right|^{n+2}}dz\biggr) dx \\ 
& \geq C \int_{B_{1}\setminus B_{2\epsilon} \cap S_{i,j} } \biggl( \int_{B_{1}} \phi(z) \epsilon^{-n} \frac{\left| \frac{x}{\epsilon}\right|^2}{\left| \frac{x}{\epsilon}\right|^{n+2}}dz \biggr)dx \\ 
& \geq C\int_{B_{1}\setminus B_{2\epsilon} \cap S_{i,j} } \left|x\right|^{-n}dx \\
& = C\int_{2\epsilon}^{1}r^{-n}m(S_{i,j} \cap \partial B_{r}(0))dr \geq C \int_{2\epsilon}^{\epsilon_{0}}\frac{1}{r}dr \gtrsim -\log(\epsilon) \to \infty,
\end{align*}
as $\epsilon \to 0$. This proves the claim, and thus the result.
Mostly, I am uneasy about how to rigorously prove the existence of such a sector $ S_{i,j} $ that does the job, though it seems intuitively true. Additionally, I am struggling to prove the $ p = \infty $ case. Roughly speaking, I think taking a function which is the convolution of the Newton potential and a mollified version of an indicator function of a cube should work. My intuition for this is that the Hilbert transform applied to an indicator of an interval furnishes a counterexample to the supposed $L^{\infty}$ boundedness of the Hilbert transform, and that this is supposed to be some sort of higher-dimensional analog. I can't quite prove that this is a genuine counterexample to $$ \norm{ \partial_{ij}u }_{L^{\infty}} \leq C \|\Delta u \|_{L^{\infty}} ,$$
as it involves pointwise estimating a singular integral and I cannot make any reduction to some favorable region (like a sector) as in the above. Appreciate some input.

Comment: In $L^1$ you can do a simpler counterexample by using $u_\epsilon=\phi_\epsilon (x)|x|^{2-n}$ whwre $\phi_\epsilon$ is zero for $|x| \leq \epsilon$ and $|x| \geq 2$ and is equal to 1 if $2\epsilon \leq |x| \leq 1$. In $L^\infty$ the simplest counterexample is $u(x,y)=xy \log (x^2+y^2)$ which shows that both $u_{xx}, u_{yy}$ but $u_{xy}$ is not. A theorem by Ornstein says that if $B,A_1, \dots A_r$ are linearly independnt differential operators with constant coefficients then no estimate of $Bu$ in the sup norm with the sum of the sup-norms of $A_i u$ (and eventualy of $u$) is possible.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune But I believe I need a compactly supported function as a counterexample no? I mean otherwise even $u(x,y) = xy$ is a counterexample? Unless you mean take this function and multiply by a cut-off to make it compactly supported.

Comment: Yes, exactly this way. All problems come from $(x,y)=(0,0)$.

Comment: By the way, if you rise to $\alpha<1$ the log term, you get a function for which the pure derivatives are continuous at 0 but the mixed derivatives tends toinfinity. A nicer example is given by $u(x,y)=(x^2-y^2) \log (x^2+y^2)$ which has a bounded laplacian in the ball, but both $u_{xx}, u_{yy}$ unbounded.